# how to enrich xml node value in mule

Tags: mule

```
input xml like below
<healthcare>
    <plans>
        <plan1>
            <planid>100</planid>
            <planname>medical</planname>
            <desc>medical</desc>
            <offerprice>3000</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan1>
        <plan2>
            <planid>101</planid>
            <planname>dental</planname>
            <desc>dental</desc>
            <offerprice>4000</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan2>
    </plans>
</healthcare>



 <set-variable variableName="newoffer" value="2000" doc:name="Variable" />
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[xpath3('//healthcare/plans', message.payload, 'NODESET' )]">
<enricher source="#[flowVars.newoffer]" target="#[xpath3('offerprice', payload 'STRING')]" >
<logger message="...#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</enricher>
<logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</foreach>
```

i want enrich xml element offerprice value as 2000 .but above doesn't do that. anybody have any suggestions. main thing is **my expected output is like below.** I'm new to mule .anyone shed light for my mule requirement.thanks in advance

```
<healthcare>
    <plans>
        <plan1>
            <planid>100</planid>
            <planname>medical</planname>
            <desc>medical</desc>
            **<offerprice>2000</offerprice>**
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan1>
        <plan2>
            <planid>101</planid>
            <planname>dental</planname>
            <desc>dental</desc>
            **<offerprice>2000</offerprice>**
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan2>
    </plans>
</healthcare>
```

Comment: no one knows answer means, don't give downvoted stuff like that . above question is very important for me .ok.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, remove the `for-each` / `enricher` elements and instead use the [XSLT Transformer](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XSLT+Transformer) that comes bundled with Mule. This is your best choice for transforming XML to XML.

Comment: not transforming one structure to other. I want to replace offerprice values in all nodes

Comment: I understood that, still XSLT is the best choice. You'll have the identity template to copy the whole structure and one specific template to rewrite the offerprice element.